# Update a column if the update query's value is not empty

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using Node.js and im trying to update my database. The SQL query looks like this

```
UPDATE user SET username = ?, email = ?, contact = ?, password = ?, type = ?, profile_pic = ? WHERE userid = ?
```

```
 dbConn.query(editUserQuery, [user.username, user.email, user.contact, user.password, user.type, img_name, userID], (error, results) => {
```

| userid | username | email | contact | password | type | profile_pic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user | example | 1234 | 123 | Admin | 1 |
| 2 | user2 | example2 | 2345 | 234 | Customer | 1 |

However, the user may not fill in all the details so some of the values will be empty. Is there a way to only update a column if the '?' value is not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the value provided to MySQL when the parameter is not set.

If this value is NULL then simply not `SET column = ?` but `SET column = COALESCE(?, column)`. So when NULL is provided then COALESCE returns existing value, and it is reassigned into (not changed), when the value other than NULL is provided then COALESCE returns it, and it is assigned to the column.

If this value is not NULL but some predefined literal (for example, empty string `''`) then use `SET column = COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), column)`. Additional NULLIF converts this predefined value to NULL (and not changed any other value) then the expression acts like described above.